# File .npy created, which should contains a 200MB dataset, is almost empty

Tags: python, numpy

I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/tree/master/Tutorial%20Codes/Part%208-13%20code) and the main goal is to balance data and save them into a second training data sheet (the first one contains data not balanced). This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from random import shuffle

train_data = np.load('training_data.npy')

df = pd.DataFrame(train_data)
print(df.head())
print(Counter(df[1].apply(str)))

lefts = []
rights = []
forwards = []

shuffle(train_data)

for data in train_data:
    img = data[0]
    choice = data[1]

    if choice == [1,0,0]:
        lefts.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [0,1,0]:
        forwards.append([img,choice])
    elif choice == [0,0,1]:
        rights.append([img,choice])
    else:
        print('no matches')


forwards = forwards[:len(lefts)][:len(rights)]
lefts = lefts[:len(forwards)]
rights = rights[:len(forwards)]

final_data = forwards + lefts + rights
shuffle(final_data)

np.save('training_data_v2.npy', final_data)
```

I really don't understand whhy it does create a 120B file while dataset weighs 200MB..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main problem is in these three lines

```
forwards = forwards[:len(lefts)][:len(rights)]
lefts = lefts[:len(forwards)]
rights = rights[:len(forwards)]
```

you are truncating the arrays.

So to confirm the final shapes of the arrays do -

```
print(len(forwards),len(lefts),len(rights))
// those 3 lines
print(len(forwards),len(lefts),len(rights))
```

You'll see the difference.

Also, try running the code without those three lines, the arrays will be 200 MB :)

P.S. I would advise you to do truncation manually -

```
forwards = forwards[:my_number]
```

and so on..

Comment: len(forwards), len(lefts), len(rights) is [32000, 0, 0]  which is strange since it should mean in the dataset there are only forwards.

Comment: Exactly, so your training data has only forwards in it or you made a mistake in generating it - causing only forwards to come. And then you truncate the data and it becomes completely empty.

Comment: Also, please upvote the answer and accept it if your problem is solved :)

Comment: So I made a mistake somewhere getting data! Thank you, I'll upvote